# Where should I store the path of a file, that my python program found?

Tags: python, file, google-chrome, directory, path

Suppose, if I wanted to open chrome using python. I would require the path of "chrome.exe". My python program does this by searching through the chrome directory in program files.

If I don't want to search through the directory, every single time I run the program. I assume that I must save the path of "chrome.exe" somewhere.

Where should I do so? Should I just store it in a .txt file in the same folder as my program, or do I store it somewhere else? I don't want anyone to alter the path, as such it causes an error in my program. How do I store it somewhere permanent, that no one can edit it except my program?

Comment: Inside your program as a string variable. Or as a variable in a `.env` if you don't want to expose your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Why not save the path in this python program then you can call get() with the path to Chrome.

Replace chrome_path with the correct path for your platform.

```
import webbrowser

url = 'http://docs.python.org/'

# Windows
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

# MacOS
#chrome_path = 'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'


# Linux
# chrome_path = '/usr/bin/google-chrome %s'

webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```